# Complex Number of C and Minimum Polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that the complex number $c = \zeta_3$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and find its minimum polynomial.

My proof:

For $\zeta_3$, consider the polynomial $m(x)=x^2+x+1$.
Given $arg(\zeta_3)$=$\frac{2\pi}{3}$, then $\zeta_3-1 \ne 0$.
Then, since $(\zeta_3-1)(\zeta_3^2+\zeta_3+1)=\zeta_3^3-1=0$, and since $\mathbb{C}$ is an integral domain, $(\zeta_3^2+\zeta_3+1)=0$.
Therefore, $m(\zeta_3)=0$.

Does this look right?  Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Looking good. Even though you already gave the reason for why the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_3$ cannot have degree $1$, you should mention explicitly that this implies that $m$ is irreducible.